# Affine Cipher: what to do if the number isnt invertible over mod n?

Tags: cryptanalysis, modular-arithmetic, affine-cipher

I am currently solving a simple cryptanalysis problem where I need to decrypt a text file using frequency analysis. The text has been encrypted using an affine cipher over a 68 character alphabet which includes lower and upper case English letters, digits from 0 to 1, as well as those characters: ". , ; : _ \n" where _ denotes space.

Going over the frequency histogram of the text, the most frequent character is "," followed by "z". According to what I know, the most frequent character for the 68 character alphabet is space followed by "e".

Thus I end up with those two equations:

$$66a + b = 63 \bmod 68$$

$$4a + b = 25 \bmod 68$$

Which gives me:

$$62a = 38 \bmod 68$$

$a = 38 \cdot 62^{-1}  \bmod 68$

However, 62 isn't invertible mod 68. I am quite new to cryptography so I am quite unsure if there is some method to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to find another equation that doesn't produces a number that is not relatively prime.

Comment: @kelalaka thank you. I actually did this and managed to find the key (5,5). Can you write this as an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: How can I find the answer without knowledge of the data. You can write your answer, too. I'll upvote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Affine Cipher Cryptanalysis](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50991/affine-cipher-cryptanalysis) another [Affine plaintext attack with GCD != 1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43932/18298), another [Decryption using affine cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/53569/18298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the whole equation throughly 2 you get
$$31a\equiv 19\pmod {34}$$
which you can solve to get $a\equiv 5\pmod{34}$. This then gives two possibilities for $a\pmod {68}$: either 5 or 39. For these two possibilities you can then find the corresponding $b$ (it turns out to be 5 in both cases) and check which solution works.